# Como é um REGEX Javascript para Código de Rastreio Correios (AZ123456789AZ)

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso de um Regex para o padrao A-Z 1-9 A-Z validando AZ123456789AZ

Já tentei `/^[[A-Z]{2}[1-9]{9}[A-Z]{2}]/$`

Comment: Já tentou algum? Se sim, é bom colocar na pergunta. Lê esse [guia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pra poder evitar receber down vote na sua pergunta.

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: sua regex funciona para isso, só é necessário tirar o [ no começo e o ] no fim, ficando assim: ^[A-Z]{2}[1-9]{9}[A-Z]{2}$/g

Comment: No final, em vez de `/$`, deveria ser `$/`

Comment: eu fiz aqui o teste meu bom, só seguir esse link: https://regex101.com/r/boeX7h/2/

Comment: `^[A-Z]{2}[\d]{9}[A-Z]{2}$` funcionou. Você pode testar em [https://regexr.com/](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: @YgorAzevedo `\d` pega todos os dígitos de 0 a 9, mas pela pergunta deu a entender que ele só precisa de 1 a 9 (`[1-9]`)

Comment: Preciso marcar como resolvido como faz?

Comment: Os numeros é de 1 a 9 ou de 0 a 9 ?

Comment: @MuriloMedeiros Como não ficou claro se os números são de 0 a 9 ou 1 a 9, coloquei uma observação sobre isso [na minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/331079/112052). Mas parece que os correios aceitam zero sim, pelo menos tem um exemplo de código com zero nesta página: https://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como comentei, sua regex está quase certa, você só precisa tirar o `[]` desnecessário, fazendo algumas correções ela ficaria assim:

```
^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}[A-Z]{2}$
```

Eu fiz um teste nesse [link](https://regex101.com/r/boeX7h/2/), você pode acessa-lo e testar algumas modificações também.

Comment: Porque com `[]` não funciona?

Comment: o [ ] define um grupo de caracteres, a-z são todas as letras minusculas sem acentuação, se colocar caracteres lá avulsos, eles são inclusos no grupo do [ ], então quando você colocou sua regex dentro disso, ela estava validando caracter [, ], {, }, 2, A-Z, 1-9, e -. Por isso a lógica implementada junto delas estava sendo invalidada.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Coloquei uma resposta explicando porque não funcionou com `[]`

Comment: Nota para quem encontrou o post pois essa postagem é a primeira que aparece no Google: Precisa ser `[0-9]` ao invés de `[1-9]` pois pacotes do correios podem ter `0` também!

Comment: @MrPowerGamerBR editado, obrigado pelo comentário :)

Comment: @Paz obrigado :), na realidade a culpa nem seria sua pois você apenas corrigiu a pergunta do OP, e no RegEx da pergunta também tem esse erro.

Mas como esse post aparece quando você procura no Google, eu achei que seria bom comentar sobre isso para não pegar alguém de surpresa.

Answer (score 7):

Apenas para complementar a [resposta do usuário @Paz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/331072/112052), uma breve explicação sobre porque a sua tentativa não funcionou.

Os colchetes definem uma [classe ou conjunto de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Por exemplo, `[ABC]` significa "a letra A **ou** a letra B **ou** a letra C". É uma expressão que vai pegar apenas um caractere.

Existem alguns atalhos como `[A-Z]`, que significa "qualquer letra de A a Z", mas também é possível colocar outros caracteres junto. Por exemplo, `[3A-Z]` significa "o dígito 3 **ou** qualquer letra de A a Z".

Dentro dos colchetes é possível também colocar o próprio colchete de abertura, ou seja, `[[]` significa "o caractere `[`" (já que ele está entre colchetes). Veja:

```js
console.log(/[[]/.test('[')); // true
```

Já o colchete de fechamento deve ser escapado com `\`, caso contrário a regex entenderá que o primeiro colchete está sendo fechado:

```js
// "]" escapado com "\"
console.log(/[\]]/.test(']')); // true
```

---

Portanto, a primeira parte da sua regex (`[[A-Z]`) significa "o caractere `[` **ou** uma letra de A a Z":

```js
console.log(/[[A-Z]/.test('A')); // true
console.log(/[[A-Z]/.test('[')); // true
```

A seguir, você coloca o quantificador `{2}`, que vai aceitar duas ocorrências desta regex, seguido de 9 dígitos e 2 letras. E no final, o último `]` corresponde ao próprio caractere `]`, já que não há um colchete de abertura equivalente (todos os `[` anteriores já foram fechados).

Isso quer dizer que a sua regex só vai aceitar strings com um `]` no final (além de aceitar `[` no início):

```js
console.log(/^[[A-Z]{2}[1-9]{9}[A-Z]{2}]$/.test('[A123456789AB]')); // true
console.log(/^[[A-Z]{2}[1-9]{9}[A-Z]{2}]$/.test('AZ123456789AB')); // false
```

Por isso o correto é remover esses colchetes do início e fim. Outro ponto de atenção é que em JavaScript uma regex é delimitada pelas barras, portanto `/$` deve ser trocado por `$/`:

```js
console.log(/^[A-Z]{2}[1-9]{9}[A-Z]{2}$/.test('[A123456789AB]')); // false
console.log(/^[A-Z]{2}[1-9]{9}[A-Z]{2}$/.test('AZ123456789AB')); // true
```

---

#### Incluir o zero ou não

Outro ponto que não ficou claro é se você precisa de todos os dígitos ou não. Digo isso porque `[1-9]` considera apenas os dígitos de 1 a 9 (ou seja, não aceita o zero):

```js
console.log(/[1-9]/.test('0')); // false
console.log(/[1-9]/.test('1')); // true
```

Caso você também precise do zero, basta trocar para `[0-9]`, ou simplesmente para `\d`:

```js
console.log(/[0-9]/.test('0')); // true
console.log(/\d/.test('0')); // true
```

Ou seja, a expressão ficaria:

```js
 // aceitar todos os dígitos (incluindo o zero)
console.log(/^[A-Z]{2}\d{9}[A-Z]{2}$/.test('AZ123456789AB')); // true
console.log(/^[A-Z]{2}\d{9}[A-Z]{2}$/.test('AZ023456789AB')); // true
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, agora não só copiei o código e colei como também sei o que colei no meu código. Parabéns pela explicação entendi certinho.

Comment: que espetáculo de explicação, parabéns!

Comment: É a perceber os erros que todos nós aprendemos! +1

Answer (score 5):

Para o padrão `AZ123456789AZ`, basta isso:

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d{9}[A-Z]{2}$
```

## Explicando:

- `^ e $`, são uma borda que representa o começo e fim de uma, são importantes porque se uma letra ultrapassar o `match` vai retornar até onde for válido, assim não validaria totalmente o padrão, o que eu expliquei pode ser visto no [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vbcOE3/1).
- `[A-Z]` conjunto que pega as letras no range de `A` até `Z`, isso não inclui as minúscula.
- `{2}` exatamente 2 letras
- `\d` atalho para o conjunto`[0-9]`